# Listview to get all data in list in JSON format

Tags: android, json, listview, android-recyclerview, hashmap

I using listview to display the response from API, which is a JSON object. Below listview, a button will be there. On clicking that button I need to get all the data from listview in JSON format.

**Activity Class**

```
package com.aryvart.myaromasupply;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.aryvart.myaromasupply.Adapter.CartListAdapterKV;
import com.aryvart.myaromasupply.Bean.CommonBean;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by android01 on 28/8/17.
 */

public class CartPageKV extends Activity implements MyInterface {
    String json = null;
    List<CommonBean> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CartListAdapterKV mAdapter;
    Context context;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    Button btn_submit;
    HashMap<String, JSONObject> hsFilterGmap;
    String value;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ListView llView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_page_kv);
        context = this;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerView);
        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        llView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ll_view);
        loadJSONFromAsset();

        //Response API
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.e("NN", "json-->" + obj.toString());

            JSONArray respArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
            Log.e("NN", "respArray-->" + respArray.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < respArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = respArray.getJSONObject(i);
                CommonBean drawerBean = new CommonBean();
                drawerBean.setStr_cart_id(jsonObj.getString("id"));
                drawerBean.setStr_cart_title(jsonObj.getString("name"));
                drawerBean.setStr_quan(jsonObj.getString("quantity"));
                drawerBean.setStr_tot_quant(jsonObj.getString("total_quantity"));
                movieList.add(drawerBean);
            }

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            mAdapter = new CartListAdapterKV(movieList, context, (MyInterface) context);
            llView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Button Click Event

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("NN:fc", String.valueOf(hsFilterGmap));
                Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = hsFilterGmap.keySet().iterator();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
                    JSONObject value1 = hsFilterGmap.get(key);
                    Log.e("NN:value", value1.toString());
                    jsonArray.put(value1);

                }

                Log.e("NN:fcAr", jsonArray.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
                System.out.println("the JSON ARRAY is" + jsonArray.toString());

            }
        });
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }


    // Interface to get Checked value from listview(Hashmap for not allowing duplicates)
    @Override
    public HashMap<String, JSONObject> getUnCheckedVal(HashMap<String, JSONObject> strVal, String str_removed_id) {

        hsFilterGmap = strVal;
        Log.e("NN:fc", String.valueOf(hsFilterGmap));
        return hsFilterGmap;
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
 package com.aryvart.myaromasupply.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.aryvart.myaromasupply.Bean.CommonBean;
import com.aryvart.myaromasupply.MyInterface;
import com.aryvart.myaromasupply.R;
import com.like.LikeButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by android01 on 28/8/17.
 */

public class CartListAdapterKV extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<CommonBean> commonBeanList;
    Context c;
    MyInterface my_interface;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    HashMap<String, JSONObject> hsMap = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();

    // constructor
    public CartListAdapterKV(List<CommonBean> movieList, Context context, MyInterface inter) {
        this.commonBeanList = movieList;
        Log.e("NN", "size-->" + this.commonBeanList);
        this.c = context;
        this.my_interface = inter;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return commonBeanList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return commonBeanList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_items_kv, parent, false);
        TextView txt_cartTitle;
        final CheckBox cb_box;
        txt_cartTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        cb_box = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxKV);
        final CommonBean recyclerBean = commonBeanList.get(position);
        cb_box.setChecked(true);
        txt_cartTitle.setText(recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title());

        //check if checkbox is checked. if yes the add value to hashmap(by default all checkboxes will be checked in listview

        if (cb_box.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "--" + recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //JSONArray req = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsoBj = new JSONObject();
            try {

                jsoBj.put("id", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                jsoBj.put("value", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title());
                jsoBj.put("checked", "true");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            hsMap.put(recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id(), jsoBj);
            my_interface.getUnCheckedVal(hsMap, recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
            Log.e("NN", "AdpaMap--" + hsMap.toString());

        } else {

            JSONObject jsoBj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsoBj.put("id", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                jsoBj.put("value", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title());
                jsoBj.put("checked", "false");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //adding the json object in hashmap to remove duplicates
            hsMap.put(recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id(), jsoBj);
            my_interface.getUnCheckedVal(hsMap, recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
            Toast.makeText(c, "-*-" + recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cb_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                final CommonBean recyclerBean = commonBeanList.get(position);
                if (cb_box.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "--" + recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    JSONObject jsoBj = new JSONObject();
                    try {

                        jsoBj.put("id", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                        jsoBj.put("value", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title());
                        jsoBj.put("checked", "true");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    hsMap.put(recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id(), jsoBj);
                    my_interface.getUnCheckedVal(hsMap, recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                    Log.e("NN", "AdpaMap--" + hsMap.toString());

                } else {

                    JSONObject jsoBj = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsoBj.put("id", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                        jsoBj.put("value", recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title());
                        jsoBj.put("checked", "false");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    hsMap.put(recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id(), jsoBj);
                    my_interface.getUnCheckedVal(hsMap, recyclerBean.getStr_cart_id());
                    Toast.makeText(c, "-*-" + recyclerBean.getStr_cart_title(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**On initial clicking of a button, I'm getting the data which is in the foreground (visible to the user), once I scroll remaining data's are getting.**

Can anyone help how can I get **entire values in listview in on button click?**

Comment: If you are populating the listView from JSON then trying to retrieve that same JSON on click then why can you not just hold the JSON after populating the listView then reference that?

Answer (score 0):

Open this **cart_items_kv** xml and place the button.
Go to the adapter
and make the event there.You can get the data of an item by position in adapter.

***another solution***

add a click after finding view

```
public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
// here `enter code here`
itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the value from adapter when I check and uncheck the checkbox. But I need whole listview data as JSON object on single button click. which is displayed below listview.